# Why is H normal in G equivalent to the conjugate of H by g being a subset of H?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H\le G$

Why are the following equivalent?

i) $H \unlhd G $

ii) $ gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$ for all $g \in G$

In other words, why do we not need to show that $H \subseteq gHg^{-1}$ for all $g \in G$ ?

Comment: I've made a minor edit to your last sentence (the inclusion was backwards, indicating the same relationship as stated in ii) above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that ii) holds for *all* $g \in G$, and you must use the containment at two different elements of $G$. More precisely, fix a $g \in G$ and assume ii) that $xHx^{-1} \subseteq H$ for all $x \in G$. Setting $x = g^{-1}$ yields the containment

$$
    xHx^{-1} = g^{-1}Hg \subseteq H,
$$

and multiplying the left and right of this containment by $g$ and $g^{-1}$, respectively, we conclude $H \subseteq gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: shouldn't $h^{-1}= g^{-1}h_1^{-1}g ?$

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I'll revise my answer shortly.

Comment: I think we could instead say that there exists $h_1$ such that $g^{-1}hg=h_1$

Comment: @settheorynoob: I've updated and simplified the argument.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: Sure thing! Happy to help! `:)`